# How to programmatically insert text into the Firefox browser search box?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a Greasemonkey script to insert text into the Firefox search box that is next to the address bar.

I wonder if it is possible, if yes then how?

Comment: I dont think you could navigate to that search box cause it is unaccessible from js. you could try to redirect your webpage to something like this: `https://www.google.com/search?q=YOUR+SEARCH+QUERY`

Comment: i already wrote a script to populate the google search box with Greasemonkey, i am wondering how to do this for the Firefox search box. Since Firefox addons can place themselves anywhere on the browser(status bar,toolbar), i think we can interact with Firefox elements.

Comment: No, addons run in a privileged environment which isn't available to userscripts.

Comment: Greasemonkey cannot do this as the lead GM dev has chosen not to expose this capability.  You must write an add-on.

Comment: Oh I see many thanks...so i am going to tackle Firefox Addons ! Since no formal answer is added, should i leave it as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that.

That's because addons (in your case GreaseMonkey) run in a privileged environment which isn't available to userscripts and if this privilage was given to the user (i mean javascript) anyone could write a script and whenever you visit their website, they could do anything with your browser (or even your device!). So in other words Firefox (or formally browser) elements are unaccessible from js.

You could try to redirect your webpage to something like this: `https://www.google.com/search?q=YOUR+SEARCH+QUERY` .

*Some parts were quoted from the comments of the question.*